# Does method -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: run in ios 2.0?

Tags: iphone, delegates, initialization

Does method -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: run in iOS 2.0?

-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is a delegate method in ios3.0 and later, Will it be wrong in ios 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not run in ios 2.0. 
"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" only in 3.0 and later.

Use this method to initialize your application and not the applicationDidFinishLaunching:  method.

Answer (score 0):

(Who are still using 2.x? o_O)

In OS 2.x the system won't know there's a `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, so it will never be called. The app will not crash because of this, just that the method is ignored.

Implement also `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` for 2.x compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

No, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` did not exist in iOS 2.x. But you may  put most initialization code in a `commonApplicationDidFinishLaunching` method and make both `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` call `commonApplicationDidFinishLaunching`. Then, both iOS 2.x and 3.x+ can share the same block of initialization code. Use a BOOL variable to avoid double calling.